# What is the proper way of using ThemeData copyWith in flutter MaterialApp widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design, flutter-layout

I was trying to change the `accentColor` after copying the `ThemeData.light()`, then I have this sample screen with a `FloatingActionButton`

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
     )}}
```

Then in the main widget in `main.dart` to call `runApp`, if I set the `ThemeData` for the `MaterialApp` widget like this, The `FloatingActionButton` will have a color of orange.

```
theme: ThemeData(
  accentColor: Colors.orange
)
```

but if I tried to inherit the color from the `Themedata.light().copyWith`, the `FloatingActionButton` will still have the color blue from the light theme.

```
theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  accentColor: Colors.orange
)
```

I was expecting the `FloatingActionButton` should have the orange color, because It inherit the `light` theme and override the `accentColor`.

Answer (score 5):

this is a common problem in Flutter, but you can solve it for now by doing the following:

```
theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    floatingActionButtonTheme:
        ThemeData.light().floatingActionButtonTheme.copyWith(
              backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
            ),
  ),
```

if you used any other button you should do the same and overwrite it's Theme,

you can read more about the problem here [Updating the Material Buttons and their Themes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54776)

and [buttonColor not honored when using ThemeData.light().copyWith()](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22711)

Answer (score 0):

look,
I don't think that u can inherit the accent color using the ThemeData.copyWith(),but if u are sure to use ThemeData.copyWith() to change your floatingActionButton Color then u can do this in the following way,

```
theme:ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    textTheme:ThemeData.dark().textTheme.copyWith(
        title :TextStyle( --your color and text configuratons here like color,font etc)
        button: TextStyle(--do--),
        ...and so on....
    )
)
```

configurations u want in your default text title will go inside the TextStyle of above title property and same for button

Now u can achieve this inside your FAB by using this,

```
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.color,
```

by doing this u can get the color u set for the buttons inside the ThemeData.

If u force on getting the default accent color then u have to use

```
theme:ThemeData(
    primaryColor: -----
    accentColor : -----
)
```

this will allow u to use Default accent Color for FAB